# Google Map api v2 blank screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I do know that this question was asked like a bazillion times but I still couldn't solve the problem
Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="chatapps.tutorial.com.fatimaarshad_assignment2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <permission
        android:name="chatapps.tutorial.com.fatimaarshad_assignment2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCshw8btydSGdry5SqJOgX7vdojQnMvv-Q" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my google_maps_api.xml

```
<resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=FC:78:21:3D:9E:21:BA:03:0E:0E:E0:C9:7D:C7:65:45:A4:9D:DA:8B%3Bchatapps.tutorial.com.fatimaarshad_assignment2

    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
    FC:78:21:3D:9E:21:BA:03:0E:0E:E0:C9:7D:C7:65:45:A4:9D:DA:8B;chatapps.tutorial.com.fatimaarshad_assignment2

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
     AIzaSyCshw8btydSGdry5SqJOgX7vdojQnMvv-Q
    </string>
</resources>
```

I have added all the permissions and api key, changed the api key twice but it is still not working. It did work before but it is not working any more.

Comment: It should show some warnings in the logs, if the map is not loaded. Did you check them?

Comment: Yes! too much output is generated

Comment: @EricB. Do you think it could be caused by a network problem?

Comment: Network could be a problem. If you get a "Google" watermark at the bottom right part of your screen. Then it means maps is configured properly.

Comment: @it's watermark does appear. I guess it is caused by network because it did work fine before

Comment: What are your logs, try filtering them using the word "map".